# StreamSocketListener not working: The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I'm trying to read messages from a local SocketServer. But the connectasync method always fails:

```
    private async void ConnectToServer()
    {
        try
        {
            _socket = new StreamSocketListener();
            _socket.ConnectionReceived += Socket_ConnectionReceived;

            await _socket.BindEndpointAsync(new HostName("192.168.1.51"), "9090");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The error is of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with message `The requested address is not valid in its context`.

I can't figure out what could be wrong, because I also declared all required capabilities in my PackageManifest

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: What device family is your application going to run on, Phone, PI, XBOX etc?

Comment: That looks right for `BindEndpointAsync`. Any chance that IP isn't the right one for that machine?

Comment: Nope the IP is correct. Weirdly enough, it works partially with StreamSocket instead of StreamSocketListener. The Client device is a Phone, the server is a PC.

Comment: "The client device is a phone" - Do you mean you're expecting this to connect to a remote device?

Comment: Yes. The code above is what is running on my phone

Comment: Right but I mean are you expecting the `StreamSocketListener` to connect to a device? If that code is running on a phone, that phone's IP should be `192.168.1.51` and it should be waiting for a connection, right?

Comment: yes, I expect the SSL to connect to a device. But 192.168.1.51 is the IP of my server, which my phone is connecting to

Comment: Well that's your problem then. You're passing a *listener* a remote IP address. A *listener* is for listening for *incoming* connections, not for connecting to something remote. You said earlier it works with a `StreamSocket` - of course! You're connecting to a remote server!